# Does anyone know how to fork a chain at a particular block on Brownie?

Tags: brownie, forks

I am trying to fork the ethereum mainnet at a past block number on brownie. But I dont see any way to do that in the [brownie docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) .

Comment: Are you using ganache or hardhat ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fork a blockchain with brownie, you actually just need to [create a network](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html) that uses a forked blockchain or uses a forking command.

### Option 1: The built-in forked chain

Brownie actually comes packed with a forked feature:

```
$ brownie networks list
Brownie - Python development framework for Ethereum

The following networks are declared:

Ethereum
  ├─Mainnet (Infura): mainnet
  ├─Ropsten (Infura): ropsten
  ├─Rinkeby (Infura): rinkeby
  ├─Goerli (Infura): goerli
  └─Kovan (Infura): kovan

Ethereum Classic
  ├─Mainnet: etc
  └─Kotti: kotti

Development
  ├─Ganache-CLI: development
  └─Ganache-CLI (Mainnet Fork): mainnet-fork <- This is the network!!
```

It uses your Infura key to fork mainnet to a forked ganache instance.

*Note: I have found more success using [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/)*

### Option 2: Add a new network that uses a forking command (recommended)

You can optionally add a network that automatically forks a blockchain of your choice.

Run the following command:

```
brownie networks add development chain-name-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 fork=RPC_URL accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

If you want to pin a specific block, add @<block_number>

```
brownie networks add development chain-name-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 fork=RPC_URL@123456 accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```

This will add a network called `chain-name-fork` that will run on `http://127.0.0.1`. You just need to pass it an `RPC_URL` for the `fork` parameter, of which blockchain it should fork.

*Note: If using `ganache`, you can use any [ganache-cli commands.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli)

You can also do this with [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) if you choose. The block pin parameter is `--fork-block-number 11095000`

### Option 3: You fork a blockchain yourself, and just point to that

Maybe, you want to run a local hardhat node like so:

```sh
npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<key> --fork-block-number 11095000
```

You'll now have a local blockchain running. You can then add it with something like:

```
brownie networks add Ethereum ganache host=http://localhost:8545 chainid=1337
```

Comment: This was a great help, do you know how to "move ahead in time" using Brownie? IE move the blockchain ahead by 30 blocks for instance?  Thanks

Comment: You can "time travel" with `chain.sleep(xx)`. For reference: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-chain.html#time-travel